# EntityKey properties of type “Geography” not supported. Entity Framework 5, VS 2012 – Database First

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, spatial

Created a SQL Server 2008 database and table with a property called “Coordinates” of type “geography”.  In VS 2012 created a project, added references to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types and EF V5. Then, using the ADO.NET Entity Data Model wizard generated the edmx.  When I compile in VS 2012 I get the following error:

```
Error   4   Error 129: The property 'Coordinates' in EntityType 'DBModel.GeoDestination' is not valid. EntityKey properties that are of type 'Geography' are currently not supported.
```

Many of the samples on the web are “code first” examples that use the type “DbGeography” as a type in their c# code and generate the database from the code resulting in a table with a property of type “geography”.

How do I do this database first and fix up the type?  It does not appear that “DBGeography” is in the drop down list of types when using the “Table Mapping” view.

Using EF 5, NET 4.5, VS 2012 SP 1, SQL Server Types

Comment: The exception says that `Coordinates` must not be marked as a key of the entity. What is primary key of your database table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.   Looks like a bug in the wizard.  If the table in SQL does not have a primary key, the  wizard automatically generates a key(s) in the resulting EF model.  It appears random, sometimes one key is generated and sometimes it makes several properties keys.  A Geography data type cannot be a key.  It was not a key in the table, but the wizard  made it a key.

Hope this response helps others.